# GridBoundColumn with multiple DataFields

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I have a GridBoundColumn that I would like to be bound to 2 fields so that I can display the two fields in one column.  I would like to do something like the following:

```
<GridBoundColumn DataField1="LastName" DataField2="FirstName" DataFormatString="{0},{1}">
```

Is this possible?  If so how can it be accomplished?

This is used in a Telerik RadGrid if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be accomplished by implementing the OnItemDataBound method (configured in your grid definition like `OnItemdataBound="GridItemDataBound"`).

Make sure that the field is uniquely identified:

```
<GridBoundColumn UniqueName="UserName">
```

Then implement your OnItemDataBound method:

```
protected void GridItemDataBound(object aSender, GridItemEventArgs anEventArgs)
{
   if(anEventArgs is GridDataItem)
   {
      string firstName = "Joe";
      string lastName = "Smith";
      GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)anEventArgs.Item;
      item["UserName"].Text = lastName + "," + firstName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a template column if you don't want to write C# code.