# RadGrid - Enter value in a cell if not null from multiple database columns

Tags: c#, sql, radgrid

So I have a database with Information and 3 columns of different types (email, decimal value, bit)
[image]

In a Radgrid I will eventually have an editable column named "Value" where ideally it is just that, a single editable value of whatever the database gives me. some int, string, etc.
I have found somethings on item databound [GridBoundColumn with multiple DataFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3450181/gridboundcolumn-with-multiple-datafields) but I have been unable wrap my head around that and apply it.  Someone also mentions templates which I have looked at and do not understand yet... This is the grid, at the moment I am just trying to get something to show in the Value Column.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" 
        OnDataBound="RadGrid1_DataBound"
        OnItemDataBound="RadGrid1_ItemDataBound">

        <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Group, DisplayName, SystemSetting, Description, value_string, value_decimal18_2, value_bit"
            AllowSorting="true">
            <GroupByExpressions>
                <telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
                    <SelectFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldAlias="Group" FieldName="Group" />
                    </SelectFields>
                    <GroupByFields>
                        <telerik:GridGroupByField FieldName="Group" SortOrder="Ascending" />
                    </GroupByFields>
                </telerik:GridGroupByExpression>
            </GroupByExpressions>
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn UniqueName="EditCOmmandColumn"></telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Group" SortExpression="Group" HeaderText="Group" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Group" Visible="false"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="DisplayName" SortExpression="DisplayName" HeaderText="Display Name" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="DisplayName"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="SystemSetting" SortExpression="SystemSetting" HeaderText="System Setting" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="SystemSetting"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="value" SortExpression="value_type" HeaderText="Value" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Value"></telerik:GridBoundColumn><%--value_string, value_decimal18_2, value_bit--%>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="Description" SortExpression="Description" HeaderText="Description" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="Description"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn UniqueName="ModifiedDate" SortExpression="ModifiedDate" HeaderText="Modified Time" HeaderButtonType="TextButton" DataField="ModifiedDate"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out how to do this.  I wound up finding the DataRowView of the event.Item.DataItem and comparing that name to what I wanted to insert. Then I made an if statement series (because I dislike switch statements).  I had an additional column in the database that described the value_type that the row is representing.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridDataItem && e.Item != null)
        {
            GridDataItem item = (GridDataItem)e.Item;
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

            if (drv["value_type"] != null)
            {
                if ((string)drv["value_type"] == "value_string")
                {
                    item["Value"].Text = drv["value_string"].ToString();
                }
                else if ((string)drv["value_type"] == "value_bigint")
                {
                    item["Value"].Text = drv["value_bigint"].ToString();
                }
                else if ((string)drv["value_type"] == "value_decimal18_2")
                {
                    item["Value"].Text = drv["value_decimal18_2"].ToString();
                }
                else if ((string)drv["value_type"] == "value_bit")
                {
                    item["Value"].Text = drv["value_bit"].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Turned out nicely!
[image]